# Kerberos failure emergency: need to filter a Wireshark capture to show only Kerberos and SPNEGO traffic

Tags: authentication, wireshark, kerberos

I am attempting to troubleshoot a serious Kerberos authentication problem on our SBS 2003 domain (none of our Windows 7 or XP workstations can authenticate).

We have logged failed Kerberos authentication instances in the system log file and are trying to use Wireshark to identify the exact cause.

A Wireshark capture was created while numerous attempts were made to authenticate with the server. How can I filter this capture to show only Kerberos and SPNEGO traffic, to hopefully give me a better idea of how we can solve this problem?

Removing then re-joining a workstation to the domain gives the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used Wireshark but I remember being able to accomplish something remotely similar; this tutorial seems to cover a similar scenario, unless there's something domain-specific that I am missing: [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/07/27/kerberos-errors-in-network-captures.aspx)

You may want to skip the first part, detailing how to obtain the capture.

Comment: Thanks. If anyone else has some specific advice on how to create the appropriate view filters it would be much appreciated.